# MexFile causing "Assertion detected" error - problem with memcpy in mexfiles?

Tags: c, sorting, matlab, memcpy, mex

This problem is unfortunately narrow, but I'm at a loss.

I have a custom mex file that takes two lists of uint32s that are each sorted and contain no common entries and returns a single sorted list containing all of the entries from both list. The code is:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "string.h"

#define MIN(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

void CalculationRoutine(uint32_T* CombinedList, const mwIndex FirstNumels, uint32_T* FirstList, const mwIndex SecondNumels, uint32_T* SecondList) {
mwIndex OutCounter = 0, FirstCounter = 0, SecondCounter = 0;
unsigned int i;

// Short-circuit if there is no ovelap.
if (*FirstList > *(SecondList+SecondNumels-1)) {
    memcpy(CombinedList,SecondList,SecondNumels*sizeof(uint32_T));
    memcpy(CombinedList+SecondNumels,FirstList,FirstNumels*sizeof(uint32_T));
    return;
} else if (*SecondList > *(FirstList+FirstNumels-1)) {
    memcpy(CombinedList,FirstList,FirstNumels*sizeof(uint32_T));
    memcpy(CombinedList+FirstNumels,SecondList,SecondNumels*sizeof(uint32_T));
    return;
}

// These can be done with no exhaustion checking. Leave one item because we
// are doing post-checking in the second loop.
for (i=MIN(FirstNumels, SecondNumels)-1; i--;) {
    if (*(FirstList+FirstCounter) < *(SecondList + SecondCounter)) {
        *(CombinedList+OutCounter) = *(FirstList+FirstCounter);        
        FirstCounter++;
    } else {
        *(CombinedList+OutCounter) = *(SecondList+SecondCounter);        
        SecondCounter++;
    }
    OutCounter++;
}

// These ones need exhaustion checking.
while (1){
    if (*(FirstList+FirstCounter) < *(SecondList + SecondCounter)) {
        *(CombinedList+OutCounter) = *(FirstList+FirstCounter);        
        FirstCounter++;
        if (FirstCounter == FirstNumels) {
            // Just copy the rest of the second list.
            memcpy(CombinedList+OutCounter+1,SecondList+SecondCounter,(SecondNumels-SecondCounter+1)*sizeof(uint32_T));
            return;
        }
    } else {
        *(CombinedList+OutCounter) = *(SecondList+SecondCounter);        
        SecondCounter++;
        if (SecondCounter == SecondNumels) {
            // Just copy the rest of the first list.
            memcpy(CombinedList+OutCounter+1,FirstList+FirstCounter,(FirstNumels-FirstCounter+1)*sizeof(uint32_T));
            return;
        }
    }
    OutCounter++;
}
}

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] ) {

mxArray *CombinedList = NULL;
uint32_T *FirstList, *SecondList;    
mwIndex FirstNumels = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]), SecondNumels  = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[1]);   

//Input Checking
if (!mxIsUint32(prhs[0])) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("FirstList must be matrix of uint32.");
}
if (!mxIsUint32(prhs[1])) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("SecondList must be a matrix of uint32.");
}

CombinedList = mxCreateNumericMatrix(FirstNumels+SecondNumels, 1, mxUINT32_CLASS, mxREAL);
if (CombinedList == NULL) {
    mexErrMsgTxt("SecondList must be a matrix of uint32.");
}

//Short circuit when we have one or the other inputs empty.
if (mxIsEmpty(prhs[0])){
    if (!mxIsEmpty(prhs[1])) {
        // Return the SecondList verbatim.
        //CopyOneInput(mxGetData(CombinedList),SecondNumels, mxGetData(prhs[1]));
        memcpy(mxGetData(CombinedList), mxGetData(prhs[1]),SecondNumels*sizeof(uint32_T));
    }
    plhs[0] = CombinedList;
    return;
} else if (mxIsEmpty(prhs[1])) {
    // Return the FirstList verbatim.
    //CopyOneInput(mxGetData(CombinedList),FirstNumels, mxGetData(prhs[0]));
    memcpy(mxGetData(CombinedList), mxGetData(prhs[0]),FirstNumels*sizeof(uint32_T));
    plhs[0] = CombinedList;
    return;
}

CalculationRoutine(mxGetData(CombinedList),FirstNumels,
    mxGetData(prhs[0]),SecondNumels,mxGetData(prhs[1]));

plhs[0] = CombinedList;
}
```

When I run code that calls the mex file, I get assertion detected errors (with stuff like Found corrupted block 381 in table 5. (invalid table index). ).  The assertions always arise, but not necessarily at the same place.

If I revert to the old version of the code, there are no problems. So something is mangling memory, but I can't see it. One of the changes I made is to use memcpy, but can't see anything wrong there.

Again, I'm sorry that this is such a narrow question, but any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: It is definitely the memcpy that is causing the assertion. If I revert to assigning values in a loop, the assertions stop. Are there restrictions with using memcpy in mex-files?

Comment: Your code runs ok on my pc. Is there a specific input which causes the assert? Did you try debugging and catching the line where it happens?

Comment: Thanks for checking, it is good to know that it is the code and nothing specific to my setup. I tried identifying inputs and catching it in the debugger, but the point where the assertion turns up changes from run to run. Matlab even reports that the assertion is turning up in other parts of the calling code (I know it is not there since switching back to the old version of the mexfile stops the assertions), so it looks like something is getting messed up in RAM which then later causes the assertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an off-by-one error in the third argument to memcpy. The while loop should be:

```
while (1){
    if (*(FirstList+FirstCounter) < *(SecondList + SecondCounter)) {
        *(CombinedList+OutCounter++) = *(FirstList+FirstCounter++);
        if (FirstCounter == FirstNumels) {
            // Just copy the rest of the second list.
            memcpy(CombinedList+OutCounter,SecondList+SecondCounter,(SecondNumels-SecondCounter)*sizeof(uint32_T));
            return;
        }
    } else {
        *(CombinedList+OutCounter++) = *(SecondList+SecondCounter++); 
        if (SecondCounter == SecondNumels) {
            // Just copy the rest of the first list.
            memcpy(CombinedList+OutCounter,FirstList+FirstCounter,(FirstNumels-FirstCounter)*sizeof(uint32_T));
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the `CalculationRoutine` function as follows:

```
// merge two sorted lists
void CalculationRoutine(uint32_T* C, const mwIndex nA, uint32_T* A, 
           const mwIndex nB, uint32_T* B)
{
    mwIndex indC = 0, indA = 0, indB = 0;

    // Short-circuit if there is no ovelap.
    if ( A[0] > B[nB-1] ) {
        memcpy(C, B, nB*sizeof(uint32_T));      // copy B
        memcpy(C+nB, A, nA*sizeof(uint32_T));   // copy A
        return;
    } else if ( B[0] > A[nA-1] ) {
        memcpy(C, A, nA*sizeof(uint32_T));      // copy A
        memcpy(C+nA, B, nB*sizeof(uint32_T));   // copy B
        return;
    }

    // loop until one of the two lists is exhausted
    while( indA < nA && indB < nB ) {
        if( A[indA] < B[indB] ) {
            C[indC++] = A[indA++];
        } else {
            C[indC++] = B[indB++];
        }
    }
    // process remaining items in the smaller list
    //if( indA < nA ) memcpy(C+indC, A+indA, (nA-indA)*sizeof(uint32_T));
    //if( indB < nB ) memcpy(C+indC, B+indB, (nB-indB)*sizeof(uint32_T));
    while( indA < nA ) C[indC++] = A[indA++];
    while( indB < nB ) C[indC++] = B[indB++];
}
```

And here is how I tested its correctness/performance:

```
numIter = 1000; numX = 250; numY = 1000;
x = sort(randi(intmax('uint32'), [250 numIter],'uint32'));
y = sort(randi(intmax('uint32'), [1000 numIter],'uint32'));
M1 = zeros(size(x,1)+size(y,1),numIter,'uint32');
M2 = zeros(size(x,1)+size(y,1),numIter,'uint32');

tic
for i=1:numIter
    M1(:,i) = mySort(x(:,i),y(:,i));
end
toc

tic
for i=1:numIter
    M2(:,i) = sort([x(:,i);y(:,i)]);
end
toc

assert( isequal(M1,M2) )
```

The timings were:

```
Elapsed time is 0.029080 seconds.        # mySort
Elapsed time is 0.074132 seconds.        # sort
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. One of the things I was trying to achieve with my algorithm was to reduce the number of times I check if we're at the end of a list. If the first list has five elements and the second has 10, we can process the first four and be certain that we haven't exhausted either list. Removing this overhead from the while loop for the early elements gives substantial speedup (especially if both lists are similar in size). Do you have any suggestions as to why my implementation is mangling memory?

Comment: @MatlabSorter: truth is I found it easier to rewrite this function from scratch than to try and debug it. Anyway both implementations would have the same time complexity if you think about it..

Comment: Fair enough, the debugging is definitely a hassle. It's driving me nuts.